# Show gallery on scrollup

Tags: android, xml

What I want is when I scroll up the scrollview the gallery should be open and when I scroll down then the surfaceview(camera) should be visible like **OLX**. I have explained my requirement in the image.hope I explained my question in proper manner.

I have explained my requirement in this image

[image]

im also posting my xml codes to let you properly understand.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context="com.example.ali.ansofexperts.Question_Photo">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview">

        </FrameLayout>
         <ScrollView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/scrollView"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          >
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:minHeight="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/click"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"></GridView>
           </RelativeLayout>
       </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your code that is attempting to get that result?

Comment: I have not write any code in java file because I dont have any idea how to do it.

Comment: _I dont have any idea how to do it._ Ok, but you wont get the code here if this is what you are looking for

Comment: `hope I explained my question in proper manner.` There is no question. And you told what you wanted but not what happens instead or what goes worong.

Comment: atleast little bit idea about design design

Comment: @greenapps yeah its a requirement

Comment: Kinf of you can use the SwypeToRefresh feature for this, with a top and bottom behaviour, not sur eif you can get ride of the refresh icons

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this Reference for beginner

**https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5987**

This Reference have the complete solution about my question,hope this will helpful.

Comment: hi bro.......i have one doubt why, all the images not showing in buttom of the view, that means in RecyclerView...for me it's showing one 10 to 20 images....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

> Refer this document you can achieve surfaceview with camer...gallery
>   party you can try your self..
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html
>
> https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

Comment: i have done the surface view code. i just need to know on slide up the scrollview how can i show image gallery